# Animate on scroll in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I know its easy to have triggers on scroll and to add class name to HTML elements through `jquery`, but I was wondering if it's possible (or even worth it) to try to do so in react or vanilla `javascript`. I am learning react and want to trigger animations when users have scrolled a certain distance of the web page. I have not used `jquery` so far as many people advise that you should stick to vanilla `javascript` as much as possible as it is very powerful and you won't require importing the `jquery` libraries.

I have implemented a scroll trigger in vanilla JS successfully with the following code bellow, although its very inefficient as it uses an event listener on the scroll (maybe `Jquery` does this anyway though?). Is jquery simply the best way to do what I want? Thanks in advance guys, here is the spaghetti code:

```
function getDocHeight(D) {
  return Math.max(
      D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
      D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
  )
}

  function amountscrolled(){
var winheight= window.innerHeight || (document.documentElement || document.body).clientHeight
var docheight = getDocHeight(document)
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
var trackLength = docheight - winheight
var pctScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100) // gets percentage scrolled (ie: 80 or NaN if tracklength == 0)

if (pctScrolled > 50) {
  document.getElementById('anim').className+=" animate";
}
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
amountscrolled()
}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the only existing answer is completely unrelated, and there is a great way to do this now – the [`IntersectionObserver` API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```js
const callback = (entries) => 
  entries.forEach(entry => 
    entry.isIntersecting && entry.target.classList.add("show")
  );

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
const animate = document.querySelectorAll(".animate");
animate.forEach(div => observer.observe(div));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body > * + * { margin-top: 1em }
#content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
.animate {
  height: 20vh;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.animate.show {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div id="content">content</div>
<div class="animate">animate me 1</div>
<div class="animate">animate me 2</div>
<div class="animate">animate me 3</div>
```

The best part is that for your React needs, there is even a library you can use!
[react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer)

```
$ npm install react-intersection-observer --save
$ # or
$ yarn add react-intersection-observer
```

(from the README)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

const Component = () => {
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    /* Optional options */
    threshold: 0,
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h2>{`Header inside viewport ${inView}.`}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```